# How to use NSScanner to scan from a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsstring

I have a string which looks like:

```
#chat :hi there
```

And I'd like to scan all the text from the `:` to a string, so it ends like `hi there`

I've tried

```
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:argument] scanUpToString:@":" intoString:&newarg];
```

But `newarg` contains only `#chat`. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example String:

```
#chat :Hello World,
#chat :How are you doing?
```

Code:

```
NSString *theString =   @"#chat :Hello World,\n"
                         "#chat :How are you doing?";

NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:theString];
NSCharacterSet *seperator = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"];
NSCharacterSet *newLine = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSString *theText;

while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:seperator intoString:NULL];
    [theScanner setScanLocation: [theScanner scanLocation]+1];
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:newLine intoString:&theText];

    NSLog(@"%@",theText);

}
```

Output:

> Hello World,
>   How are you doing?

Comment: Thanks!
Notice that the setScanLocation may fall out of bounds of the string length. 
You should add the following check: `if ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO)...`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an if statement to iterate through the scan. You've always told the computer to scan everything until the character ":", but it sounds like you actually want to scan everything AFTER the ":" character. Anne's answer provides an excellent example of such.